# deleting history chrome extension

Tags: javascript, json, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup

I am trying to create a simple Chrome Extension that deletes the selected Browsing History attributes. I have followed several tutorials and I have tried to keep the programming as simple as possible given that I am new to JS, JSON, and HTML. Moreover, since I could not find anywhere to compile my code, it is very difficult to pin point my errors. Could anyone take a look at my code and point out to me what is wrong? I am simply wanting to learn and so what I am looking for is a bit of explanation as well. However, anything helps. Here are my popups and manifest:

manifest.json:

```
{

"name": "1-Click Clear",
"description": "1 click and your Chrome history is cleared!",
"version": "1.0",

"manifest_version": 2,

"browser_action":{
"default_icon": "icon.png",
"default_popup": "popup.html"
},

"permissions":[
    "history",
    "topSites",
    "browsingData"
]



}
```

popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="history" value="male"> Delete History<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cookies" value="female"> Delete Cookies<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cache" value="other"> Delete Cache <br>  
  <input type="checkbox" name="passwords" value="female"> Delete Passwords <br>
</form> 
<br>

<button type = "submit" id = "all"> <b>Clear All Above</b></button>
 <button type = "submit" id = "chosen"> <b>Clear Chosen</b></button>



</body>
</html>
```

popup.js:

```
var callback = function(){};
var millisecondsPerMonth = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4;

var oneMonthAgo = (new Date()).getTime() - millisecondsPerMonth;

function clear()
{
    if(document.getElementsByName("history").checked)
    {
        chrome.browsingData.removeHistory("since": oneMonthAgo,callback);
    }
    if(document.getElementsByName("cookies").checked)
    {
        chrome.browsingData.removeCookies("since": oneMonthAgo,callback);
    }
    if(document.getElementsByName("cache").checked)
    {
        chrome.browsingData.removeCache("since": oneMonthAgo,callback);
    }
    if(document.getElementsByName("passwords").checked)
    {
        chrome.browsingData.removePasswords("since": oneMonthAgo,callback);
    }
}

function clearAll()
{
    chrome.browsingData.removeHistory("since": oneMonthAgo,callback);
    chrome.browsingData.removeCookies("since": oneMonthAgo,callback);
    chrome.browsingData.removeCache("since": oneMonthAgo,callback);
    chrome.browsingData.removePasswords("since": oneMonthAgo,callback);
}


document.getElementById('chosen').addEventListener('click',clear);
document.getElementById('all').addEventListener('click',clearAll);
```

EDITED popup.js:

```
var callback = function(){};
var millisecondsPerMonth = 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24 * 7 * 4;

var oneMonthAgo = (new Date()).getTime() - millisecondsPerMonth;

function clear()
{
    if(document.getElementsByName("history").checked)
    {
    chrome.browsingData.removeHistory({"since": oneMonthAgo}, callback);
    }
    if(document.getElementsByName("cookies").checked)
    {
         chrome.browsingData.removeCookies({"since": oneMonthAgo}, callback);
    }
    if(document.getElementsByName("cache").checked)
    {
        chrome.browsingData.removeCache({"since": oneMonthAgo}, callback);
    }
    if(document.getElementsByName("passwords").checked)
    {
        chrome.browsingData.removePasswords({"since": oneMonthAgo}, callback);
    }
}

function clearAll()
{
    chrome.browsingData.removeHistory({"since": oneMonthAgo}, callback);
chrome.browsingData.removeCookies({"since": oneMonthAgo}, callback);
    chrome.browsingData.removeCache({"since": oneMonthAgo}, callback);
chrome.browsingData.removePasswords({"since": oneMonthAgo}, callback);
}


var doc = document.getElementById('chosen');
if(doc)
{
    doc.addEventListener('click',clear);
}
var doc = document.getElementById('all');
if(doc)
{
    doc.addEventListener('click',clearAll);
}
```

EDITED popup.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<script src="popup.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="checkbox" name="history" value="male"> Delete History<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cookies" value="female"> Delete Cookies<br>
  <input type="checkbox" name="cache" value="other"> Delete Cache <br>  
  <input type="checkbox" name="passwords" value="female"> Delete Passwords <br>
</form> 
<br>

<button type = "submit" id = "all"> <b>Clear All Above</b></button>
 <button type = "submit" id = "chosen"> <b>Clear Chosen</b></button>



</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You don't have to compile anything, but you should include your Javascript code in the popup.html, i.e. `<script src="popup.js"></script>`

Comment: Please [edit] the question to be on-topic: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include: ►the desired behavior, ►a specific problem or error *and* ►the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: "**How to create a [mcve]**", [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), and [ask].

Comment: Wrong *object literal* syntax, use curly braces like shown in the documentation: `{"since": oneMonthAgo}` or `{since: oneMonthAgo}` (you can omit quotes for the key name). To view the errors rightclick your popup and choose Inspect, which will open devtools, then view the console.

Comment: @IvánNokonoko Alright I added that in, thank you!

Comment: @wOxxOm Alright thank you very much I fixed the syntax and used the console to debug some of the next bugs.

However, now it is showing no errors, but the extension does nothing. It does not delete anything. I will repost the changed code for anyone that could take a look, thank you in advance.

Comment: Remove `type = "submit"` from both buttons.